# Creating an android Button which can perform more than one task

Tags: android

I am making an android app which requires a button to perform two taks:
1. The button should show an Error message in a TextView when user supplies a wrong input in EditText.

1. If the user provides a correct input then on clicking the button, it will jump to another activity.

My app is a kind of a simple game which contains 4 activities(activity_1, activity_2, activity_3, activity_4).
It asks for an input in activity_2. If it gets a wrong input the it gives the Error message.
But on providing the correct input the app crashes.

code activity_2.xml :

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/buttonClickMe"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
 android:onClick="sendMessage"
 android:text="@string/button_start" />
```

code activity_2.java :

```
final Button buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)
buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            int no = Integer.valueOf(numberField.getText().toString());

            switch (no)
            {
               case 1 : maxRand = 15;  // the random number will be between 0 and maxRand
               break;
               case 2 : maxRand = 30;
               break;
               case 3 : maxRand = 50;
               break;
               case 4 : maxRand = 100;
               break;
               default : textField.setText("Invalid Argument, Please try again.");
               break;
            }

            if(maxRand != 0){
                randNumber = (int) (Math.random() * maxRand);
                /*textField.setText("Now click Start button !");
                  buttonStart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);*/
                startActivity(intent);   //This starts a new activity
            }
        }
    });
```

and the code followed by the onClick method :

```
public void sendMessage(View view){     //This method is called everytime when the button is clicked

    intent = new Intent(this,ShowResultsActivity.class);
}
```

Ive declared intent as the data member of the class.

Please do help me. And remember to provide bunch of code for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try initiating Intent in setOnClickListener itself

final Button buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)
buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        int no = Integer.valueOf(numberField.getText().toString());

        switch (no)
        {
           case 1 : maxRand = 15;  // the random number will be between 0 and maxRand
           break;
           case 2 : maxRand = 30;
           break;
           case 3 : maxRand = 50;
           break;
           case 4 : maxRand = 100;
           break;
           default : textField.setText("Invalid Argument, Please try again.");
           break;
        }

        if(maxRand != 0){
            randNumber = (int) (Math.random() * maxRand);
            intent = new Intent(this,ShowResultsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);   //This starts a new activity
        }
    }
});
```

If it doesn't fix the problem. pate your  logcat output here..

Comment: The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<ShowResultsActivity>) is undefined

Comment: yes this is because you are initiating it inside the listner. try giving your class name before this.. try below

intent = new Intent(YourCurrentClass.this, ShowResultsActivity.class);

Answer (score 0):

```
public void sendMessage(View view){     
    //This method is called everytime when the button is clicked
    int no = Integer.valueOf(numberField.getText().toString());

            switch (no)
            {
               case 1 : maxRand = 15;  // the random number will be between 0 and maxRand
               break;
               case 2 : maxRand = 30;
               break;
               case 3 : maxRand = 50;
               break;
               case 4 : maxRand = 100;
               break;
               default : 
                   textField.setText("Invalid Argument, Please try again.");
                   // add this to ensure that you won't start activity
                   maxRand = 0;
               break;
            }

            if(maxRand != 0){
                randNumber = (int) (Math.random() * maxRand);
                intent = new Intent(this,ShowResultsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);   //This starts a new activity
            } else {
                   // maxRand == 0 ===> ERRORS, update your textField here
                   textField.setText("Invalid Argument, Please try again.");
            }
}
```